# How to attach one event to multiple selector in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I attach one event to multiple selector?

for e.g.

```
 $("#selector1 #selector2").change(function() { //not a valid code
       alert("hi");
       ... }
```

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use commas between selectors. If you want multiple events, you'll need to use `on` and specify there

```
$("#selector1, #selector2").change(function() { //not a valid code
    alert("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set class values to both selectors

```
<input class="className" id="selector1"....
<input class="className" id="selector2"....


$(".className").change(function() { //not a valid code
       alert("hi");
       ... }
```